# Override a class method with a template method in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm still figuring out C++, and I have not been able to put this together from searching on google. I'm working with a larger project used by other people and I'm trying to expand the functionality of a class without breaking anyone else's code. In particular there is an untouchable Base class and Derived class that both implement a "crunch numbers" method that works on std::vector.

```
class Base {
 public:
    void crunch_numbers(std::vector& v) { // do stuff to v; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
    void crunch_numbers(std::vector& v) override { // do different stuff to v; }
};
```

I'm working with Eigen::Vector, and I was hoping to get away with something like this:

```
template <typename vec>
class MyDerived : public Base {
 public:
    void crunch_numbers(vec& v) override { // do different stuff to v; }
};

typedef MyDerived<std::vector> Derived;
```

That would let me work with different vectors and wouldn't break any existing code that uses the Derived class. But, when compiling my code, I get the error error: `‘void MyDerived<vec>::crunch_numbers(vec) [with vec = Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>]’ marked ‘override’, but does not override.` ... Because Base class only operates on std::vector.

I can't touch Base class because there may be other derived classes I don't know about. I'd like to have the flexibility to work with different vector types in the future without just adding overloads to Derived class. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There's overriding. And there's overloading. There's no overwriting in either C++, Java, C# or Vb .net.

Comment: If you can't modify base you're stuck with the function overload route.

Comment: The base class code is already wrong because it pass the vector by value. Obviously, if you want to override a method, it must exist in a base class and `MyDerived` does not derives from any classes (so does Derived).

Comment: You won't be able to override the function to use the polymorphic behaviour unless it is marked `virtual` in the base class

Comment: Ok, I edited typos in the original question: Derived and MyDerived both derive from Base. Vectors are in fact passed by reference. It still sounds like my only option is to use a bunch of overloads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that `override` is correct only for one instantiation.

and we don't have conditional `override` (as we have for `noexcept`)

The simplest is to drop completely `override`:

```
template <typename vec>
class MyDerived : public Base {
 public:
    void crunch_numbers(vec& v) { /* do different stuff to v; */ }
};
```

So regular cases works,
but the true override case is not checked.

Else you can use specialization... but you would have some duplication just to add `override` in a specific case.